# Updating an empty dictionary inside a list of dictionaries changes all elements of the list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list with empty dictionaries. If I update one element of the list, I see same changes in all other elements as well.

```
my_list = [{}] * 5
print(my_list)
my_list[0]["name"] = "john"
print(my_list)
```

Outputs:

```
[{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
[{'name': 'john'}, {'name': 'john'}, {'name': 'john'}, {'name': 'john'}, {'name': 'john'}]
```

I expected an output like this:

```
[{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
[{'name': 'john'}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: ^ it doesn't matter that the above is about lists, the principle is the same

Comment: `[{}] * 5` That creates five identical references to the same dict object.  Updating one of them updates all of them, because they're _the same object_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It creates a list of references to the same dictionary.
Try using something like this :
`my_list = [dict() for x in  range(n)]`
where n is the number of ducts you want

Comment: Please do not answer questions that should not have been asked, or have a clear duplicate already on the site.